# VBA-JSON Nested Collection Parse into Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am using the VBA-JSON module from link below, the source from where the weather information is capctured from has changed from a list strcture for 7 day's data being hourly listed, into an array for the day, and each day has another arrary for the hour.

This is the module I have imported into VBA as a Marco.
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

forecastday and hour is an collection object when converted using this VBA-JSON library, I am not familiar with VBA....how should I correct the two lines within the for loop to have data displayed like the image attached ? (This was how the system worked before the http source changed)

```
http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=4c6f7219367f4aa5b0c174927231104&q=51.180224,-113.9385224&days=7&aqi=no&alerts=no
```

[image]

```
Public Sub exceljson()

Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "GET", "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=4c6f7219367f4aa5b0c174927231104&q=51.180224,-113.9385224&days=7&aqi=no&alerts=no", False
http.Send

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

For i = 4 To 169

Sheets("Setup").Cells(i, 1).Value = JSON("forecast")("forecastday")("hour")(i)("time_epoch")
Sheets("Setup").Cells(i, 2).Value = JSON("forecast")("forecastday")("hour")(i)("temp_c")

Next

End Sub
```

[image] (expected excel results)

The following two lines in the loop is where it generates an error when executed.

```
For i = 4 To 169

Sheets("Setup").Cells(i, 1).Value = JSON("forecast")("forecastday")("hour")(i)("time_epoch")
Sheets("Setup").Cells(i, 2).Value = JSON("forecast")("forecastday")("hour")(i)("temp_c")

Next.
```

But I am unsure how to handle nested collection objects. Should there be an (j) and (i) ? j for < 8 for number of days in a week? I read that JSON converter for VBA converts any [] values into a VBA collecton object.

Whatever I tried either give runtime error 5 or 13.

Should this be the expected format? But it's not accepted when debugged. I believe forecastday should be looped 7 times for the days in a week, and then for each day there should be a hourly loop for the 24 hours in a day? Not sure how to acheive that in VBA.

```
JSON("forecast")("forecastday")(j)("hour")(i)("temp_c")
```

Please help,how can I do this? I have attached expected results in an image called "(expected excel results)" for a tab called "setup" there's colume A starting at row 4 recording epooch timestamp entries, column B is the forecasted temperature for that day, predicated hourly.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) may be of some help in understanding how the JSON is parsed and the objects that are created. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59718352/4717755) may also help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for providing these links I will read upon it to gain a better understand of the concept, not a programmer by profession, so this was not intitutive for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `forecastday` is actually a collection and not dictionary, you need to loop through the 7 days and then the 24 hours. Therefore, consider a nested loop with row and column iterators. Below returns *all* elements of `hour` except for nested `condition`.

```
Public Sub exceljson()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim http As Object, JSON As Object
    Dim currHour As Dictionary
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, row As Long, col As Long

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    http.Open "GET", "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=4c6f7219367f4aa5b0c174927231104&q=51.180224,-113.9385224&days=7&aqi=no&alerts=no", False
    http.Send
    
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)

    row = 2
    For i = 1 To JSON("forecast")("forecastday").Count
        For j = 1 To JSON("forecast")("forecastday")(i)("hour").Count
            Set currHour = JSON("forecast")("forecastday")(i)("hour")(j)
            col = 1
            For Each k In currHour.Keys
                If row = 2 Then
                    Sheets("Setup").Cells(1, col) = k               ' HEADER
                End If
                If k <> "condition" Then
                    Sheets("Setup").Cells(row, col) = currHour(k)   ' DATA
                    col = col + 1
                End If
            Next k
            row = row + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    
ExitHandle:
    Set currHour = Nothing: Set JSON = Nothing: Set http = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Output

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, this is a vaild answer that worked for me! I added a test condition If k = "time_epoch" Or k = "temp_c" Then 'Or k = "time" to get only these 3 attributes. Wondering if the script would be exected fasted if it were changed somewhere here? Set currHour = JSON("forecast")("forecastday")(i)("hour")(j) It takes a bit of time but does what I'd like it to do, thanks again!